# Note5 read Mifare classic card UID

Tags: java, android, nfc, mifare

I am working on an app that reads just the UID of MIFARE Classic cards. However, every time I scan a card on my Galaxy note 5, I get a toast message "NFC tag type not supported" and the UID doesn't show up.

I know that because NFC Chip of my phone isn't compatible to Mifare Classic, but is there any way to fix it?

```
static void showToast() {
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
        Tag tag = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
                "The UID for this card is:" + bin2hex(tag.getId()), 
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
}

static String bin2hex(byte[] data) {
    return String.format("%0" + (data.length * 2) + "X", new BigInteger(1, data));
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you taken care to register intent filters for ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED, provide xml with list of techs, declare uses-permission android.permission.NFC, declare uses-feature android.hardware.nfc and make a call to showToast in the onNewIntent() callback of your activity ?

Comment: Yes I did all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Galaxy Note 5 doesn't support Mifare Classic. See here: https://www.shopnfc.com/en/content/7-nfc-compatibility#samsung
Mifare Classic is proprietary of NXP and so whichever device Samsung used NXP's chip (Galaxy Note 2 Note 8, Note 9), Mifare classic is supported.
Since it requires hardware change, there is no way you could get this working on your Note 5.

Comment: Thank you very much.
I downloaded an app from the play store and it works very good on my mifare card, do you have any idea how they do it.

Comment: May I know the app name

Comment: NXP DWM application

Comment: This thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35906081/hide-nfc-tag-type-not-supported-error-on-samsung-galaxy-devices indicates that on a rooted phone its possible enable support for Mifare classic. I don't have code of Samsung's tweaks to NFC framework to check where they have disabled the support. These NXP apps, most probably, are using Foreground Dispatch System. To confirm, can you tell if NXP DWM app detects the tag even when NOT in foreground? Another possibility is that the card you are using has an AAR, To confirm share card dump obtained using NXP TagInfo app.

Comment: It works only in foreground, when I tried it in background the error message "NFC tag type not supported" appeared.

Comment: If it suffices to read the UID when your app is in foreground only, add foreground NFC capabilities according to https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/advanced-nfc#foreground-dispatch. If you need the functionality with your app in background as well you can try the suggestions in the other thread.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I will try it.

Comment: I used foreground dispatch, but the code still not showing the UID.

Comment: I believe the initial problem of "NFC tag type not supported" is no more seen. What's the error or behavior seen now with foreground dispatch enabled ?  Suggest you to take a logcat for working(NXP DWM app) and non-working(your app) cases and compare.

Comment: This message "NFC tag type not supported" still appears and nothing change.